# Smoother way to exit a void recursive Java function

Tags: java, recursion

So I wrote this function that behaves like Knuth's Algorithm X. Just for illustration - the function requires a large matrix of possible rows among which it tries to select the combination of the ones that make up for a legitimate solution.

The thing is, once we found the solution, since its void, the function doesn't return anything and instead just backtracks up (which consequently means it prints out sudoku for every level in the recursion depth).

Any suggestions on how to end the function the moment the solution is found? I am currently using System.exit(0) but that isn't nice since the program then ends the moment you find the solution (so anything you want to do afterwards is impossible - for example run the function on array of sudokus and solve each one).

The code is here:

```
public static void solve(ArrayList<int[]> solution, ArrayList<int[]> coverMatrix) {

    if (Arrays.equals(solvedCase, workCase)) {
        //this means we found the solution

        drawSudoku(testOutput);
        System.exit(0);

    } else {

        //find the column we didnt yet cover
        int nextColToCover = findSMARTUnsatisfiedConstraint(coverMatrix, workCase);

        //get all the rows that MIGHT solve this problem
        ArrayList<int[]> rows = matchingRows(coverMatrix, nextColToCover);

        //recusively try going down every one of them
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {

            //we try this row as solution
            solution.add(rows.get(i));

            //we remove other rows that cover same columns (and create backups as well)
            removeOtherRowsAndAdjustSolutionSet(coverMatrix);

            if (isSolutionPossible(coverMatrix)) {
                solve(solution, coverMatrix);
            }

            // here the backtracking occurs if algorithm can't proceed
            // if we the solution exists, do not rebuild the data structure
            if (!Arrays.equals(solvedCase, workCase)) {
                restoreTheCoverMatrix(coverMatrix);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `return;`

Comment: Check out my answer it should work for you...

Comment: Is it a requirement that the function returns `void`, or that it only takes two parameters?

Comment: I would use return but then i have problems restoring the covermatrix - its more convenient for restoring that way - unless you could suggest the restoring part since so far nothing except this worked as it was supposed to @RC

Comment: Then make solve return true if solved and adjust your algorithm

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to end recursion when you got the first solution. You can achieve this by having boolean return type for the method, and return true when you get first solution :.

```
    public static boolean solve(ArrayList<int[]> solution, ArrayList<int[]> coverMatrix) {

if (Arrays.equals(solvedCase, workCase)) {
    //this means we found the solution

    drawSudoku(testOutput);
    return true;

} else {

    //find the column we didnt yet cover
    int nextColToCover = findSMARTUnsatisfiedConstraint(coverMatrix, workCase);

    //get all the rows that MIGHT solve this problem
    ArrayList<int[]> rows = matchingRows(coverMatrix, nextColToCover);

    //recusively try going down every one of them
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {

        //we try this row as solution
        solution.add(rows.get(i));

        //we remove other rows that cover same columns (and create backups as well)
        removeOtherRowsAndAdjustSolutionSet(coverMatrix);

        if (isSolutionPossible(coverMatrix)) {
            boolean result = solve(solution, coverMatrix);
            if(result  == true) return result;//else continue
        }

        // here the backtracking occurs if algorithm can't proceed
        // if we the solution exists, do not rebuild the data structure
        if (!Arrays.equals(solvedCase, workCase)) {
            restoreTheCoverMatrix(coverMatrix);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: The question clearly states that it is a void function by adding a return type you no longer are helping OP to solve their issue.

Comment: @StackFlowed The method was originally void as OP did not want to return any meaningful "result", such as calculation output. But as he is writng the method, and it is in full control, there is no harm changing void to boolean which achieves the expected result. Also as side effect, it can tell whether any "solution" was detected or not.

Comment: I would leave that to the OP to decided if the want to change the return type or not. I was pointing out is at this point of time you are not answering the question that OP has asked. You are answered a different question in which you have assumed that OP is wiling to change the return type.

Comment: @StackFlowed ok, I'd leave that to OP to. But OP did not specifically mention that he is willing to change method return type, does not mean the he against it. Sometimes we have to think about the overall problem perspective, not only on the "unfinished" solution.

Comment: Please read the title of the question `Smoother way to exit a void recursive Java function` after all this argument i still don't think your code will work because you are returning true but not using that value.

Comment: @StackFlowed I read it, but I still think my previous comment holds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AtomicReference` Class with a `Boolean`:

---

```
public static void solve(ArrayList<int[]> solution, ArrayList<int[]> coverMatrix, AtomicReference<Boolean> test) {
```

---

```
if (Arrays.equals(solvedCase, workCase)) {
    //this means we found the solution
    drawSudoku(testOutput);
    test.set(true);//System.exit(0);
}
```

---

```
solve(solution, coverMatrix, test);
```

---

```
if(!test.get())
{
    // here the backtracking occurs if algorithm can't proceed
    // if we the solution exists, do not rebuild the data structure
    if (!Arrays.equals(solvedCase, workCase)) {
        restoreTheCoverMatrix(coverMatrix);
    }
}
```

---

You can call your method like this(just initialize the `Boolean` to `false`):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    AtomicReference<Boolean> test1 = new AtomicReference<Boolean>();
    test1.set(false);
    solve(***, ***, test1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could misuse the concept of exceptions for that, although I would not recommend it.

First define a custom exception class.

```
public class SuccessException extends Exception {}
```

Throw an instance on success.

```
if (Arrays.equals(solvedCase, workCase)) {
    drawSudoku(testOutput);
    throw new SuccessException();
}
```

Call the function initially in a `try` block.

```
try {
   solve(solution, coverMatrix);
} catch(SuccessException e) {
   /* Solution found! */
}
```